# Do I get full damage on my abilities if the animations fall behind the activations?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have a Sith Sorcerer, and I've noticed that if I activate Force Lightning immediately after casting Lightning Strike (as soon as the casting bar fills but before the actual animation completes), I can get almost halfway through the cast bar before the actual animation starts (because it's still finishing the Lightning Strike animation).

When this happens, does my Force Lightning still deal all it's ticks of damage?

Comment: Good question.  I am pretty sure the answer is yes, but you should be able to tell for sure from your combat log.  There are some animation issues that will *delay* damage, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was playing with my commando I noticed that the animation of the ability  `Full Auto` was delayed. This was also with some other abilities.

I looked at the dps numbers above the enemy npc and I noticed that I got all the damage of the abilities even though I couldn't see the animation.